# Categorical plot with datetime axis format seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been trying to create categorical plot with date time data as the y axis
[image]

```
plot = sns.catplot(x="step",y="time",hue="product",kind="point",data=table)
plot.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout
```

However, I keep getting error message

```
Could not interpret input 'time'
```

I have been trying to use other method to convert but not successful yet (probably because I'm not familiar at all with this)

Anyone has suggestion for this? Thank you

Comment: There's no `proc_time` in your code. Are you sure this is the exact code producing the error?

Comment: Sorry, the error message suppose to be 'time'